# How do I override MyModel.new(attributes) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a normal rails app, if I have a model named MyModel an instance of it can be created via

`MyModel.new(attributes)`

If MyModel inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, how can I override the "new" method?